# Commas in lists of items which themselves contain commas

Tags: punctuation

An illustrative example I have in mind is, say, a list of coordinates I would like to typeset:

```
$(0,1),(2,3),(3,4),\ldots$
```

I find that this looks a bit ugly to the eye, my best guess as to why this is the case being because the comma between "`(0,1)`" and "`(2,3)`" is 'on the same footing' as the comma in "`(0,1)`" itself, at least as far as the TeX is concerned, whereas it really shouldn't be.

I had tentatively decided to use semicolons instead when the items in a list themselves contain commas:

```
$(0,1);(2,3);(3,4);\ldots $
```

I am still not entirely satisfied with this, however---it seems inconsistent to have something like this alongside

```
$\varepsilon _1,\varepsilon _2,\varepsilon _3,\ldots $
```

when there aren't any commas in the items of the list.  For the sake of consistency, I would then feel like I should be using semicolons *all the time* to separate items in lists, which just seems plain weird to me, if only because I've never actually seen anyone else do this.

Is there a 'proper' way (or at least a better way) to typeset lists of items which themselves contain commas?

Comment: Do you mean this: `$(a{,}b), (c{,}d)$`? IMHO your 1st code is right.

Comment: Yes!  I like it!

Comment: There's also this possibility: `ˆ$(a, b),\, (c, d) ,\, (e, f)$`.